$x_{1}=\frac{1}{x_{1}}+x_{2}=\frac{1}{x_{2}}+x_{3}=\ldots=\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}+x_{n}=\frac{1}{x_{n}}$; prove that $x_{1}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{n+2}$
If $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots, x_{n}$ are $n\geq 2$ positive real numbers such that $
x_{1}=\frac{1}{x_{1}}+x_{2}=\frac{1}{x_{2}}+x_{3}=\ldots=\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}+x_{n}=\frac{1}{x_{n}}$, prove that $x_{1}=2 \cos \frac{\pi}{n+2}$.
The problem reduces to solving the recurrence ${x_{1}}x_{n-1}=1+x_{n}x_{n-1}$. I was stuck at this. How do I solve this recurrence?
I have tried by defining a function $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$ then $f(x_{1})=x_{2},$$f(f(x_{1}))=x_{3},$ and by induction $f^{n-1}(x_1)=x_n$ and I don't know how to approach further??

As it's currently stated your question is unclear. Edit to make it clear and include some context and attempts.

@Sahaj i have edited, suggest some hints

https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/ComplexCos.pdf theorem 3
